Mongoose - Conditionally update fields in the update query
I have the following query which pulls an id from two arrays (requests and followers) in the document:
User.updateOne(
    { _id: otherUserId },
    { $pull: { requests: userId, followers: userId } }
)

I want to modify this query by using a condition stating if the userId is in the requests array, then pull from requests but don't update the followers array. If the id is not in requests, then pull from followers. Currently, both fields are updated regardless. Any way to accomplish this using one query?
I tried the following code, however it returned a CastError
User.updateOne(
    { _id: otherUserId },
    { $pull: { requests: userId, followers: {$nin: [new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId), "$requests"]} }}
)


An Aggregation Pipeline should be able to achieve it.
requests:

$filter - Filter the requests array to remove the userId if it exists.

followers:

$cond - Check userId is not in the requests array.
If true, remove the userId from the followers array.
Else, remain the followers array.

User.updateOne(
{ _id: otherUserId },
[
  {
    $set: {
      requests: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$requests",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$this",
              userId
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      followers: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $not: {
              $in: [
                userId,
                "$requests"
              ]
            }
          },
          then: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$followers",
              cond: {
                $ne: [
                  "$$this",
                  userId
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          else: "$followers"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Demo @ Mongo Playground

One question I have is that when using $set, are the fields updated sequentially, or at the same time? For example, in the example above, will the requests be updated first, and once it's complete, then the followers is updated? Or are both fields inside the $set updated asynchronously and at the same time? Thanks

Hi would say the fields are updated in the same time as they are within the same stage.

and by same stage you mean they’re both in the set stage ?

what would happen if they’re were in different stages? Could you give me an example of this ?

In different stages, there will be two $set stages. db.collection.update({}, [{$set: ...}, {$set: ...}]), the stage are run in sequence. I doubt the query with multiple stages can work correctly in your scenario. For example, when the userId is firstly removed from the requests array, when executing the second $set stage, you can't use the same logic to check whether userId doesn't exist in the requests array with $cond (it definitely returns true).
